# Como puedo asociar objetos de un Arraylist a otra?

Tags: java, poo, eclipse

Tengo tanto las latas como las botellas plasticas creadas (objetos) y están almacenadas en un ArrayList en un DAO, lo que no puedo hacer es asociar una lata o botella a un Proveedor (clase), que respectivamente tambien tiene su DAO.

probe con existentes.add y todo pero no puedo :(

```
public static void agregarProductoProveedor() {
    List<Producto> existentes = dao.obtener();
    List<Proveedor> existentes2 = dao2.obtener();
    Producto pr;
    int seleccionprov, seleccionprod;
    System.out.println("Proveedores:");


    for(int i=0; i < existentes2.size(); ++i) {
        System.out.println(i +" " + existentes2.get(i));
    }

    seleccionprov = cu.getEntero("el numero del proveedor que deseas seleccionar");
    existentes2.get(seleccionprov);
    System.out.println("Proveedor seleccionado");

    for(int k=0; k < existentes.size(); ++k) {
        System.out.println(k +" " + existentes.get(k));
    }

    seleccionprod = cu.getEntero("el numero del producto que desee agregar al proveedor");
    existentes2.get(seleccionprod);
```

Comment: Define "asociar". ¿A qué te refieres con asociar?

Answer (score 1):

Necesitarías tener campos en tus DTO (clases) para poder tener esa relación. ej:

```
public class Producto {

  String nombreProducto;
  String idProveedor;
   // getters,setters, constructores,etc.
}

public class Proveedor {

  String nombreProveedor;
  String idProveedor;
   // getters,setters, constructores,etc.
}
```

Un ejemplo visual sería:

```
 new Producto("silla","1A");
 new Producto("20","2B");

 new Proveedor("SO EduBw","1A")
```

Y recorres los array :

```
 for(int k=0; k < existentes2.size(); ++k) {
     for(int i=0; i < existentes.size(); ++i) {
        // ahora comparas si el producto pertenece al proveedor
        if(existentes2.get(k).getIdProveedor().equals(existentes.get(i).getIdProveedor())){
           System.out.println( "El producto:" + existentes.get(i).getNombreProducto + " pertenece a " +  existentes2.get(k).getNombreProveedor);
        }
    }
  }
```

El resultado sería silla con el provedor EduBw

Necesitas en tus tablas un campo para poder "relacionar" los productos con sus proveedores, después recorres los array buscando esa relación.

Otra opción es hacer directamente una consulta que te devuelva a los productos con sus proveedores y así no tendrías que recorrer nada.